# Sorting .gz files in a directory

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have following files in my directory - `case-1.gz , case-2.gz, ........ , case-12.gz, index.xml` . Below is my code to sort the files in alphabetical order -

```
$dir = '/var/www/html/es/a';
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir,1), array('..', '.', 'index.xml'));
print_r($files);
```

which outputs as follows -

```
    Array
(
    [1] => case-9.gz
    [2] => case-8.gz
    [3] => case-7.gz
    [4] => case-6.gz
    [5] => case-4.gz
    [6] => case-3.gz
    [7] => case-2.gz
    [8] => case-12.gz
    [9] => case-11.gz
    [10] => case-10.gz
    [11] => case-1.gz
)
```

I need to have an array with the pattern `case-12.gz, case-11.gz, case-10.gz, case-8.gz, ........ , case-1.gz`

Also in my above output offset 0 of array is missing as I need to access the top most sorted files in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [<kbd>**natsort**</kbd>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) along with the [<kbd>**array_reverse**</kbd>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) as

```
natsort($arr);
$array = array_reverse($arr);
print_r($array);
```

[<kbd>**Fiddle**</kbd>](https://eval.in/407770)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but offset 0 is still missing in the array. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I think that might be because of `array_diff`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/sort) (and `natsort`):

```
<?php
natsort($files);
print_r($files);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but offset 0 is still missing in the array. Do you have any idea about that?